# Does MongoDB index collections name itself?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

Does MongoDB index collections name itself ? 
I want to create a database which might contain up to million collections. If MongoDB index collection names itself then would be good, otherwise having huge amount of collections in 1 database is not a good idea.
(To clarify: I'm talking about "Collection" not "Documents inside Collection").

Comment: "million collections" or million documents?

Comment: collection is nosql analog of sql's tables, you dont need to create collections dynamically(excepting some, very rare cases), instead you need to create documents.

Comment: Why not have a collection that contains what you need as collection as a field inside, and make it the index?

Comment: What @bureaquete mentioned is: Compound Index and Index Intersection. I am aware of this approach. But I want a clean way to store documents. Student A has a lot of document, so do Student B. I read, write and change values of documents daily so MongoDB has to resort daily. So let say: Student A is very lazy and don't touch his documents for a week, then I just deal with a collection of Student B,  I don't have to mess with student A's stuff. Both approach work. I'm not sure which way is better.

Answer (score 1):

Mongodb does not index the collection names in a way you would be expecting. It might do it internally for its speedy operations, but it will not affect much for you while executing a query.

Secondly, having million collections seems not an efficient idea. You may experience following problems :

- You need to store how many collections you have and it belongs to which user/website etc in a different collection. So you add an extra layer to every queryw whener you need to retrieve any record for a perticular user/website. I mean you first need to go find its collection name and then you go for the main query.
- The documents can be indexed, so if you have 100 million documents, its still efficient to search for a particular user/website's data from those documents if you index the field properly.
- If you need to change any format the entire data structure and add a flag for example, you need to do the query for all collections. Having a single collection, its really easy.
- If you have million collections, you will have more million indexes or more than that. That's really a large number for an index.

Comment: There are 2 approaches for this: each collection will have "entity" as its name. I have SQL database to store that information already. Each entity has its own separate set of documents which I put inside a separate collection, containing averagely 5000 documents. I already wrote additional layer, which takes entity name to get exact collection and obviously it works. My concern is: Does MongoDB index collection name itself (internally like you said) so this approach is efficient? ----  Second approach is to use compound index or index intersection, it also works. Which way is better ?